# Universal Credits and community service?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales, common-law, punishment

I have read many cases of criminals within the United Kingdom, focusing on England and Wales, being given community service rather than a prison sentence.

What I am curious to discover is whether they are still able to receive financial benefits from the state (Universal Credits) when they have been sentenced to community service? It would seem a bit unfair that they still receive an income, when ordinary members of the public would have to take unpaid time off of work...

Comment: Are the ordinary members of the public also forced to do community service? If not, I see no problem here.

Comment: PMF Someone who is unemployed will find it a lot easier to do community service than someone in employment. I wouldn’t get paid if I had to do community service.

Comment: I was interested in the law/rules - if someone is on Universal Credits because they are unemployed, do they still get their monthly payments whilst they do community service as punishment for breaking a law and being found, or pleading, guilty?